# Search a string in visual studio including ressource files and showing usages of localized strings containing the searched element

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, localization

I want to know if a way exists (or an extension) for searching a string in visual studio that also return the places where a localized string containing the searched pattern are used.

For instance, I have a two messages in a ressource file (.resx)

```
 <data name="Msg_001" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Please enter this person's name</value>
  </data>
  <data name="Msg_002" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Please indicate this company's name</value>
  </data>
```

And somewhere in my c# code

```
var name = "Georges";
```

I would like to be able to search the word "name" and have in my results the line above (as usual) but also every usages of Msg_001 and Msg_002 since they are actually replacing a string containing the word "name"

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> Will help you search in every place within the solution

For instance, this is the dialog that you will see:

[image]

There you can specify all the parameters that you might use to find stuff in your files. You can even use regular expressions if you want. The results are going to be shown in a new `result console screen`

There is also a very cool (paid) extension called [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/?gclid=Cj0KEQjw9b6-BRCq7YP34tvW_uUBEiQAkK3svQ_Knd91Dw90UOqCCJt72xUeQ8QS47yPtsaaAIPTls4aAtje8P8HAQ&gclsrc=aw.ds.ds&dclid=COec3KS9_c4CFcRPhgodbVMH5g) that lets you do a bunch of cool things if you are interested in other options

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not really what I need. When you search for a string using ctrl + shift + F you'll see every where this string is used including Ressource files but not where the localized strings are used.

Comment: I guess you need my second option then. [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html) tracks the usage of any type, object, or class. Follow the link so you get an idea of how it works

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer on both questions. I have resharper but it does not allow what i need to do. I can search a string, I can find usage of a localized string but I can't do both at the same time.